# Executing jar produces different console output compared to IDE execution

Tags: java, windows, file, powershell, filewriter

I'm working on a Java University project with IntelliJ and when I run the main function inside the IDE I get this console output:

[image: Console output inside IDE]

However, when I build a jar and execute it in Windows powershell using this command: `java -jar myJar.jar arg1 arg2 arg3` I get a different console output:

[image: Console output in Powershell]

The output in the second case was supposed to be written in a file, not to console using this function:

```
private static void writeToFile(String term, int docID, int freq) {
    if(term.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) { // Contains only letters
        String path = "index//" + term + ".txt";
        try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path, true)))) {
            out.print(docID + "," + freq + " ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

How is it possible that the output of the above function is printed on the console instead of file only in Powershell and not inside the IDE? Have I done something wrong that I can change?

PS: The last number output in the second case in produced by another function not mention here, but it would be normal if it was in a file.

Comment: Could it be that `out` at runtime resolves to `System.out` which in a Windows console application (like powershell.exe) translates to the Console output? Please try with a different variable name for the `PrinterWriter`

Comment: I can try and change the name. ;) I'll let you know if it's effective.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Unfortunately, this didn't work.

Comment: maybe you are using an old jar which writes to System.out? Try to delete and rebuild it.

Comment: @wero Really not. I deleted everything that has to do with artifacts (both in the out folder IntelliJ produces and the MANIFEST), created the artifact again, built it and ran it, but no luck.

Comment: Could you construct [mcve], which demonstrate such behavior?